# the relationship between generating function and recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the existence of a generating function of a sequence imply the existence of recurrence relation of the same sequence?

Comment: What do you mean by "existence of a generating function"? Given any sequence $a_n$ whatsoever, I can make up the formal power series
$$A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n.$$
In this sense, a generating function exists for every sequence (including, of course, ones that do not satisfy any recurrence relation).

Answer (score 1):

No. As Zev Chonoles noted, 
you can create a generating function (GF) for
$any$ sequence.

What make a recurrence come from a GF
is that the GF have certain properties.
Some properties that do this are:

1. The GF is a rational function. This directly results in a recurrence.
2. The GF satisfies a differential equation. This often, but not always, results in a recurrence.
3. The GF satisfies a quadratic equation. The Catalan numbers do this.

See Wilf's "generatingfunctionology" for lots more. It is available for free download at http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html.